# Converting php mysql results into an array

Tags: php

I have got this function:

```
    public function get_all_sites($niche){
    $query="SELECT * 
           FROM sites AS site
           INNER JOIN niche AS n ON n.niche_id=site.niche_id
           INNER JOIN review AS r ON r.site_id=site.site_id
           WHERE n.niche_id=".$niche;
    $results=mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

  while($rows[] = mysql_fetch_assoc($results));

    return $rows;
}
```

What i want to do is to convert all the rows into an associative array in one go and return it. Since there are many values returned, I dont want to use any push functions or write code like this $new_array['id']=$row['id'];. A shorter code is better.

Okay, the connection error is gone. How can I output get all the rows as an array out of mysql_fetch_assoc without fetching the results from inside the loop

Comment: **`mysql`** `_query` vs **`mysqli`** `_fetch_assoc` . Two different extensions. I would suggest switching to mysqli or PDO entirely, and leaving the old `mysql_*` functions alone to die.

Comment: well, I am rushing to finish this site..so i will stick to mysql

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions for new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun the [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the [**red box**](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help to choose. If you care to learn, [here is a good PDO tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Comment: I am learning them.. for this site, i dont care to use mysql..cause it barely uses databases

Comment: @DmitryMakovetskiyd it only takes one query to compromise your database. The fact that you barely use the database is never an excuse.

Answer (score 0):

The error:

```
Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, 
resource given in C:\Program Files (x86)\Zend\Apache2\htdocs\bestMatch
\sandbox\models\SitesDB.php on line 19
```

means that there is something wrong with your SQL or the server isn't able to execute it. I would suggest you echo it out and make sure that the query can supply a result.

In this case, it seems you are mixing mysql_ and mysqli_ functions? Are you making  mysqli_ connection to be able to return an associated array?

Edit:

based on this comment "well, I am rushing to finish this site..so i will stick to mysql" , try adding a connection to your function? Look at [example 1](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php) and make sure you have the steps covered.

Comment: @DmitryMakovetskiyd Normally if I was sure that my connection was fine, I would echo out the SQL to see where the error was, in this case though, it seems as if you are trying to use two sets of functions incorrectly. `mysql_*` and `mysqli_*` do not mix.